# Can gcc/gcov be made to output coverage stats to a location other than the source folder?

Tags: gcc, gcov, code-coverage

When using gcc with -fprofile-arcs and -ftest-coverage, when the resulting executable terminates, it tries to create .gcda output files in the same location as the .o files used to compile the executable.  This is inconvenient when I'm running on a different machine than the one I built on -- is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `GCOV_PREFIX`. It's mentionned in the doc under a ["cross-profiling" section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross-profiling.html), which itself is referred to in the documentation for `-fprofile-arcs`.

Comment: If I want to move executable from a "compile machine" to a "target machine", where program will be executed and coverage will be measured: do I have to move "*.gcno" files generated by the compiler (for example "main.cpp.gcno" generated for my source file main.cpp) ?